# not able to create new project

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

I am making new android project from file menu->new->project and it is showing this `dialog`

[image]

can anyone help me to create a new project. 
I am using android studio 3.0

Comment: Have you set android SDK before creating new project?

Comment: yes..I was able to create new project before

Comment: I think u have not set  SDK location before creating new project

Answer (score 0):

Under Java click on Gradle and then click next. I have never seen that UI before but that is what your looking for.

Answer (score 0):

When I was upgrading the Android studio to 3.1.2 at that time I was also facing the same problem. To solve this, You have to enable the Android Support Plugin. Make sure it's enabled.

**Go to Setting -> Plugin -> Clicked on Android Support-> It gives you a popup to enable -> Click Ok**

After that restart the Android studio. Please see the below image to enable that option.

It solved my problem, you can also try. It may help you.

[image]